# How to connect Sequel Pro with Laradock

Tags: docker, laradock

I can not connect my Laradock docker with Sequel Pro.

In my .env file

```
### MYSQL
MYSQL_VERSION=8.0
MYSQL_DATABASE=default, athsurvey
MYSQL_USER=homestead
MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB=./mysql/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

And in my Sequel Pro interface, I put :

```
host: 127.0.0.1
user: homestead
pass: secret
```

But it does not work. Do you have an idea of how to make my connection successful? It should be simple ...

thank you very much!

Comment: I think it is related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38914665/sequel-pro-with-mysql-in-docker

Answer (score 2):

There's a known issue currently with [Sequel Pro](https://www.sequelpro.com) connecting to MySQL 8 that's still unfixed yet, reference: https://github.com/sequelpro/sequelpro/issues/2699

Also [TablePlus](https://tableplus.io/) has similar issue (despite it's said to be working), reference: https://twitter.com/Omranic/status/1011385798820859904

Currently I'd advice using either command line, or Jetbrain's [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) which works fine with MySQL 8, or as a final option if you don't mind which version of MySQL and you're developing locally, you can downgrade to v5.7 until these GUI tools are being fixed and be ready. Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the MYSQL related environment variables in laradock's `.env` file?
Homestead/root combo is not familiar as default credentials for me.

Try `root/root` for user/pass combo and `default` for database.

Answer (score 0):

Using `MYSQL_USER=homestead` and `MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret` are not the default options. If you have edited `laradock/.env` file after the container was already started at least once, you should rebuild the MySQL container so changes are applied.

```
docker-compose stop mysql
docker-compose build --no-cache mysql
docker-compose up -d mysql
```